# 'Settings' are missing in top bar menu ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04

After updating from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 I noticed that there is no shortcut to 'Settings' in top right menu/dropdown. I believe it was there right after update and it disappeared somewhere down the line. On the same day I was re-installing `wine` (had to downgrade some deps) and `pulse-effects` (had issues with equalizer - had to add plugins manually).

I tried reinstalling gnome control cener using:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

I tried re-enabling the option in both `gsettings` and `gnome-tweak-tool`. I was not able to find the option.

[image: menu I'm having problems with]

Answer (score 6):

I ran

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

as you proposed. This command installed `gnome-control-center`, which appeared not to be installed.

After that, I had to log out and to log in to see the "Settings" entry appear in the menu dropping from the upper right button in the top taskbar.